# Rewards of a non-muslim

Tags: salat, non-muslim, shahada

I am a non-muslim learning about islam and there are many things that I agree with for example, salah, wearing the hijab, eating halal food ect. I started to read salah, wear the headscarf and eating halal food because I feel that it is right and that I want to do it for Allah SWT because I know that He is watching me and I feel guilty not doing otherwise. I feel that I am starting to believe more and more in Islam everyday, however, I still have not said my Shahada because I do not feel completely ready to do so yet, but In Sha Allah someday I can take that next step.

Will I be rewarded for reading Salah or wearing hijab ect even though I believe that I am doing it for Allah SWT but I have not said my Shahada?

Comment: How can you believe in Allah and not say the shahadah? The Shahada is stating that you believe in Allah and if you do believe in Allah, it makes no sense that you haven't said the shahada.

Comment: I think a similar question has been asked (by Rebecca?) before.